# CSS inheritance not working

Tags: html, css

**Screenshot 1**

[image]

**Screenshot 2**

[image: After modification according to the suggestive answer]

I am currently stuck on a css issue. Basically I have defined a style rule like this:

```
#divMyList tbody tr td{
    cursor:pointer;
    border-right:5px solid white;
    padding:10px;
    width:200px;
}
```

I'm applying another class named `tmenu` on my `td` in the `<div>` like this:

```
<td class="tmenu"> foo </td>
```

so that it inherits all the color and other combinations from  along with my overridden styles in `#divMyList tbody tr td` I mentioned above. This is working fine for me.

Now, I want to implement the selected style of `tmenu` to my current `<td>` element so that when someone clicks on it, it inherits the selected style of `tmenu` class. The `tmenu` and its selected styles are defined like this:

```
.tmenu {
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
}

.tmenu ul li {
    /* ..... */
}

.tmenu ul li.selected {
    cursor: default;
}
```

When I do like this:

```
<td class="tmenu selected">foo</td>
```

it doesn't apply the rules of the selected class to my td element. Any help on what I'm doing wrong. Do I need another rule mixing all of these in a new class?

Comment: Why do you have `ul` and `li` elements in the style?

Comment: As Zach and Steve said, you need to have `.tmenu .selected` instead of the stuff you do with the `ul` and `li`. Also, in order to make the css change when the user clicks, you need to add or remove the class `tmenu selected` with JavaScript (preferable JQuery) so that the css does or doesn't get inherited.

Comment: I'm dynamically applying that selected class in using the following: $('#divMyList tbody tr td').each(function () { var colId = $(this).attr('id'); if (colId == id) { $(this).addClass('selected'); } else { $(this).removeClass('selected'); } });

The reason why I have ul and li elements is that it's a top style menu which has been built up using that and I can't make a change as it's already implemented at many places

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the way you have defined your table, your css should look like this

```
#divMyList tbody tr td{
    cursor:pointer;
    border-right:5px solid white;
    padding:10px;
    width:200px;
}

.topmenu {
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
}

.topmenu td.selected{
    cursor: default!important;
}
```

I have put together a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/u4oedpx9/1/) and added a color to show that it is getting styled

Comment: this is probably a better fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/u4oedpx9/3/ shows the comparison

Comment: Rachel, I have just added a picture to show you that's what I was trying when you posted your answer, have a look and please suggest. ("it's still not working")

Comment: Thanks, yes I can understand what's being implemented. Only difference in my case is that in my selected class, I don't need to apply any background or foreground colors in topmenu td.selected as they should be inherited from:
.topmenu ul li.selected
attaching another picture for you

Comment: add the picture to your own question

Comment: you don't need to add the colors they are just for effect

Comment: Thanks Rachel, I figured out that the background color was being applied dynamically from code behind, which is fixed and everything is working at my end now.

Comment: Great. Happy to help :)

Answer (score 2):

```
.tmenu ul li.selected { [...] }
```

Is going to look for an element structured like this:

```
<elem class="tmenu">
  <ul>
    <li class="selected"> </li>  <!-- This is going to get styled! -->
  </ul>
</elem>
```

It sounds like what you are looking for is this:

```
.tmenu.selected { [...] }
```

Keep in mind something needs to apply the `selected` class to tmenu, and that it won't automatically happen by simply clicking on it.

Comment: Let me have a look on it.
yes I'm dynamically applying that selected class in using the following:
 $('#divMyList tbody tr td').each(function () {
                        var colId = $(this).attr('id');
                        if (colId == id) {
                            $(this).addClass('selected');
                        }
                        else {
                            $(this).removeClass('selected');
                        }

                    });

Comment: I have defined it like this:
.tmenu.selected {
        cursor: default;
    }
and my table structure is now like this:
<div id="divMyList">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="topmenu">
                   <td class="selected"></td>
but it's still not working, can you please identify what am i missing here

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ASP.Net Forms application try `document.getElementById('MainContent_test').innerHTML = carName;`

If you do an 'Inspect' when you run the application you will see that ASP.Net renders the control with 'MainContent_[your control ID]' as the ID.

Once you get the name right it works.